# Simplex - Network flow problem : Arc from 1 to P with infinite capacity

Tags: optimization, simplex, graphs, network-flow

The Network - Maximum flow problem below aims to find the maximum flow using simplex method :

[image]

With the LP as follow :

LP : \begin{Bmatrix}
Z(Max) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} fi \\ 
Af =0 
\end{Bmatrix}

Incidence Matrix :

[image]

*With arcs indexed {1,2,3,4,5} in red.*

---

**Question part**

As mentioned above, I need to get the Maximum Flow using the simplex method. 
Can someone please solve it, and explain to me how to they did.

**Edit :**

To solve this problem using the simplex method I had to add artificial variables, which gave me the following LP :

\begin{Bmatrix}
f_{1} + f_{2} - f_{5} = 0\\ 
f_{1} + f_{3} = 0\\ 
-f_{2} + f_{4} = 0\\ 
-f_{3} -f_{4} + f_{5} = 0\\ 
\\
f_{1}\leq 4\\ 
f_{2}\leq 4\\ 
f_{3}\leq 2\\ 
f_{4}\leq 3
\end{Bmatrix}

Comment: Do you understand how to apply Simplex here? How would you do it? What have you tried?

Comment: The last row of your incidence matrix is incorrect.  Note that each column should one $1$ and one $-1$, with the other entries $0$.

Comment: @dhasson yes, I just added how I did proceed to solve this problem, to solve this problem using simplex method I added artificial variables which gave me the LP -I added above- which it should be solved using simplex method, and here we come to the point I where I struggle.

Comment: @RobPratt thank you sir, I just corrected the last row of the incidence matrix and added how did I proceed to get the LP which I'm struggling to solve using the simplex method

Comment: Your arc 5 and matrix column 5 do not match.  Your matrix row 2 and constraint 2 do not match.

Comment: I think in the picture, "Ur" is displayed in the wrong direction. It is an artifical arc that you want to maximize the flow on. I think, everything is written down and you just have to solve the LP. (In this tivial case, you can "see" the maximum flow, it is 3+2 = 5.)